# Извлечь российские города из названий файлов

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Есть список из названий файлов

```
files = ['Downloads/report_2023-02-19_Москва.xlsx',
 'Downloads/report_2023-02-19_Нижний Новгород.xlsx',
 'Downloads/report_2023-02-19_Пермь.xlsx',
 'Downloads/report_2023-02-19_Новосибирск.xlsx']
```

При попытке извлечь российские города, у меня следующий результат:

```
import re
for b in files:
    for n in re.findall(r'(?<=_)[а-яА-Я]\w+', b):
        print (n)
```

Результат:

```
Москва
Нижний
Пермь
Новосибирск
```

Нужен следующий результат:

```
Москва
Нижний Новгород
Пермь
Новосибирск
```

Comment: print('Downloads/report_2023-02-19_Нижний Новгород.xlsx'.split('.')[0].split('_')[2))

Comment: Либо `.rpartition('_')[2].partition('.')[0]`, например

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Поменял регулярку, включив в поиск пробелы. Поменял метод поиска на `re.search`:

```
import re
for b in files:
    m = re.search(r'(?<=_)[а-яА-Я ]+', b)
    print(m.group())
```

Результат

```
Москва
Нижний Новгород
Пермь
Новосибирск
```

Answer (score 0):

ИМХО там еще может быть Комсомольск-на-Амуре. И после названия города идет "." и расширение, т.е. что-то такое:

```
r'([А-Яа-я]+[- А-Яа-я]+?)\.'
```